# require dynamically module created by webpack in react

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have a page with two tabs:

- 1 simple page that displays "hello"
- 2nd page that has a form that requires some libraries to run correctly

I've created a webpack configuration where I'm creating a vendor bundle (stuff needed by this 2nd page) that I would like to be required only on that 2nd page when I explicitly go to that page.

So my webpack.configuration looks like this:

```
entry: {
  vendor: [
    '!script!lib-needed/1.js',
    '!script!lib-needed/2.js',
  ],
  app: './app/app.jsx'
},
output: {
  path: __dirname,
  filename: './public/[name].js',
  publicPath: './public/'
}
```

webpack creates then two bundles:

- app.js - I'm loading this in html code
- vendor.js - I want this to be loaded only when I click on the 2nd tab

Below is a react component where I need this vendor.js:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  onFormSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // do some stuff where lib is needed
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>Test</div>
        <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
          <input type="search" ref="something" placeholder="Type something"/>
          <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is I know how to require on this page component created by me but I don't know how to load module created by webpack (vendor.js).

Comment: This may help: https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html

Comment: @Scarysize I've already read it and I have two bundles. The page you sent does not describe the situation I've described (or maybe I'm missing something).